# graphml file containing emojis getting converted to black nodes in gephi

Tags: visualization, emoji, gephi, graphml

Good morning, I am trying to visualize an emoji graphml file in gephi, however, when I import it in, it keeps showing the black dots like here:

[image]

I am not sure what is going on. Am I missing something? Please give me little direction if you could, I am using Windows 10. I have never used the gephi before, and did a google search related to the problem, found few blogs, but that also didn't work out. Here is content of graphml file which I wrote it in R:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
         http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<!-- Created by igraph -->
  <key id="v_name" for="node" attr.name="name" attr.type="string"/>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n3">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n4">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n5">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n6">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n7">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n8">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n9">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n10">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n11">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n12">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n13">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n14">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n15">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n16">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n17">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n18">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n19">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n20">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n21">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n22">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n23">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n24">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n25">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n26">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n27">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n28">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n29">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n30">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n31">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n32">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n33">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n34">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n35">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n36">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n37">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n38">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n39">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n40">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n41">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n42">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n43">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n44">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n45">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n46">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n47">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n48">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n49">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n50">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n51">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n52">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n53">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n54">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n55">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n56">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n57">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n58">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n59">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n60">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n61">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n62">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n63">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n64">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n65">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n66">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n67">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n68">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n69">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n70">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n71">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n72">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n73">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n74">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n75">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n76">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n77">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n78">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n79">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n80">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n81">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n82">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n83">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n84">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n85">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n86">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n87">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n88">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <node id="n89">
      <data key="v_name"></data>
    </node>
    <edge source="n0" target="n64">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n1" target="n24">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n2">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n2">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n3" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n4" target="n5">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n5" target="n5">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n6">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n6">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n2">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n5" target="n5">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n2">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n2" target="n7">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n7">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n6">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n6">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n4" target="n65">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n8" target="n66">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n9" target="n14">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n10" target="n49">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n11" target="n67">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n42">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n13" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n14" target="n68">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n15" target="n17">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n11" target="n16">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n12">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n17" target="n64">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n18">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n10" target="n69">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n19" target="n22">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n10" target="n20">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n70">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n71">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n21">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n22" target="n72">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n23" target="n25">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n15" target="n26">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n12">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n73">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n16" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n15" target="n16">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n12">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n22">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n15" target="n26">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n74">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n12" target="n24">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n22" target="n25">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n26" target="n26">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n27" target="n75">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n3" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n6" target="n12">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n31">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n30">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n31">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n33" target="n45">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n24" target="n46">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n34">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n35">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n35" target="n47">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n4" target="n59">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n36" target="n76">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n37">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n45">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n38" target="n45">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n39" target="n39">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n40" target="n77">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n41" target="n78">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n31">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n42">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n78">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n43" target="n79">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n24" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n44" target="n44">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n80">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n31" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n30">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n13" target="n15">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n22" target="n30">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n45" target="n45">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n45" target="n45">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n43" target="n79">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n37">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n43" target="n79">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n46">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n40" target="n77">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n41" target="n78">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n32">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n49">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n25" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n32" target="n47">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n47" target="n81">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n16" target="n16">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n16" target="n47">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n7" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n29">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n49">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n49" target="n49">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n49">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n52">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n50" target="n82">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n51" target="n54">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n28" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n28" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n28" target="n28">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n52">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n16" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n48">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n48" target="n53">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n53" target="n53">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n54" target="n54">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n55" target="n83">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n29" target="n84">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n47" target="n65">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n37">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n24" target="n30">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n56">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n57" target="n85">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n24" target="n37">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n58" target="n86">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n87">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n30" target="n59">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n24" target="n60">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n37" target="n47">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n47" target="n61">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n61" target="n61">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n62" target="n88">
    </edge>
    <edge source="n63" target="n89">
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

**Edit**: I have enabled the labels, but I see node id, not the emojis themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the plugin called imagepreview. The trick is, you need to have nodes as emoji images, and those emojis must have their utfs encoding as their name. You would also need a JAVA 6 JDK because a plugin hasn't seen an update since 2015.

If you have the imagepreview plugin installed,  you should see a Node Images section at the bottom of the right-side Preview Settings bar. Tick Render nodes as images and specify the folder where the photos are located in the field below. And then have your data containing utfs point to the photo names.